# Linkit One- Connect rc522 rfid with linkit one

Tags: rfid

Linkit One is a board based in Arduino by mediatek. 
I am trying to connect a rfid reader with it [link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mifare-RC522-Card-Read-Antenna-RF-Module-RFID-Reader-IC-Card-Proximity-Module-/261268585155?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3cd4d23ac3)
I am trying from past 3 days to get it working, checked my code wiring but nothing seems to get it working. 
The reader is perfectly working because i tested it on raspberryPi and it worked flawlessly. 
In my linkit board i am able to detect the reader but card is not getting scanned. 
I am using this library [GitHub](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid)
and my code is fairly simple one

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#define RST_PIN 9   //
#define SS_PIN  10  //
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Create MFRC522 instance
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial communications with the PC
while (!Serial); // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
SPI.begin(); // Init SPI bus
mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522
ShowReaderDetails(); // Show details of PCD - MFRC522 Card Reader details
Serial.println(F("Scan PICC to see UID, type, and data blocks..."));
}
void loop() {
// Look for new cards
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
return;
}
// Select one of the cards
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
return;
}
// Dump debug info about the card; PICC_HaltA() is automatically called
mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));
}
void ShowReaderDetails() {
// Get the MFRC522 software version
byte v = mfrc522.PCD_ReadRegister(mfrc522.VersionReg);
Serial.print(F("MFRC522 Software Version: 0x"));
Serial.print(v, HEX);
if (v == 0x91)
Serial.print(F(" = v1.0"));
else if (v == 0x92)
Serial.print(F(" = v2.0"));
else
Serial.print(F(" (unknown)"));
Serial.println("");
// When 0x00 or 0xFF is returned, communication probably failed
if ((v == 0x00) || (v == 0xFF)) {
Serial.println(F("WARNING: Communication failure, is the MFRC522 properly connected?"));
}
}
```

This program in theory should detet reader and when card is scanned should display the UID.

I am getting msg that my card is v2, so its detecting the reader but not reading the card. 
[image]

Comment: Same problem here. It seeems there is a problem writing to registers. the self test of the chip returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link worked for me:

http://www.grantgibson.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/ggrfid_en_ino.txt

Found it in a forum:

> Please have a look at this ino file
>   http://www.grantgibson.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/ggrfid_en_ino.txt
>   this ino file works with my reader  but this rc522 library does not
>   https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid  I want to know the difference as
>   i was not able to spot any, one works and another does not.
>
> Please let me know if there is any editing to be done so to get
>   https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid this working

Answer (score -1):

my friend, i have some problems with version 2.0 trying to read some cards. i think that the problem when  u cant read the card is this version . i have both version 1.0 and 2.0, version 1.0 detect all card type, and 2.0 some not. 
for me is a big problem because, here in argentina i only found version 2.0. maybe change on library some.

Comment: This is not even an answer, its just going along with question.